Calculation of Chern number from non-Abelian Berry connection
Does the calculation of Chern number using the Fukui method (Eq.16 of this paper) consider the non-Abelian Berry connection(i.e. $F = \partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x + [A_x, A_y]$)? Or Is it simply adding the individual band's Chern numbers ((i.e. using Abelian Berry connection $F = \partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x$)) in a different way?
Any clarification regarding this is appreciable!
